# foreach loop for gridview.row[e.rowindex]

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, gridview

I have wired a gridSearchResults_RowUpdating event for everytime an update link button is clicked. What I want to do is loop through the row at the event rowindex and add the textbox value in the row cell to a string collection. I am having troubh accessing the textbox in the cell. If this doesn't make sense my code should help make things clearer.

**HTML**

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("jobTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("jobTitle") %>' ReadOnly="true"
                        BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px" Width="80">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' ReadOnly="true"
                        BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px" Width="80">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' ReadOnly="true"
                        BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px" Width="80">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Address" SortExpression="EmailAddress">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmailAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmailAddress") %>' ReadOnly="true"
                        BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px" Width="80">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Telephone Number" SortExpression="TelephoneNumber">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTelephoneNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TelephoneNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTelephoneNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TelephoneNumber") %>' ReadOnly="true"
                        BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px" Width="80">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="Company">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Company") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Company") %>' ReadOnly="true"
                        BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px" Width="80">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEditLink" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancelLink" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdateLink" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**C#**

```
protected void gridSearchResults_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
        GridViewRow row = gridSearchResults.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        foreach (gridviewrow c in gridSearchResults.Rows[e.RowIndex])
        {

        }
}
```

So does anyone know a good way of looping through the cells of a gridview row and grabbing the textbox value in the gridview row cell. Thanks

Comment: `gridSearchResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells` or `gridSearchResults.Colums`. But to get the control in a TemplateField you use `row.FindControl("controlID")`.

Comment: What you get is one row, so you need to loop the cells or move to the exact cell if you know the index or better gridSearchResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl

Comment: I want to avoid explicitly hard-coding each FindControl("txtControlName") if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (TableCell cell in gv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells) 
{
    TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)cell.FindControl("txtControlName");
    // or if you don't want to hard code the control name and assuming that there is only 1 control in the cell then use this:
    TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)cell.Controls(0);
}
```